# How to add dynamic css for each node?

Tags: theming, 8

I need to apply dynamic css for each node. I have stored the css into the database for each row of the page.

I have generating css like `node_57002-en.css` here, 57002 is a node-id with language code for each responsive layout. 
For eg. If I select width for desktop layout for `node-id-57002` then `node_57002-en.css` generated with below code.

`@media only screen and (max-width:991px) {}@media only screen and (max-width:767px){}`

I have to find out the better solution becouse, everytime generated  the new css for each node. Below is the code which I used,

```
$styles = $nodeProcessor->getStyles();
$rowCss = $styles->getDesktop() . "@media only screen and (max-width:991px) {" . $styles->getTablet() . "}" . "@media only screen and (max-width:767px) {" . $styles->getMobile() . "}";
$cssPath = $modulePath . '/resources/css/rows/node_' . $this->_nid . '-' . $this->_langCode . ".css";
$cssPath .= '?' . filemtime($cssPath);
```

[image]

I have some questions on this,

1. How to get that css from db and how to apply on front-page in
   drupal manner.
2. How to cache the library css and how to clear the cache when css
   updated?
3. If not then what is the alternative option.

I referred [Dynamically generated CSS and JS](https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/assets#dynamic-css-js) document but it is only for dynamic js. I really appreciate if anybody helps me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the CSS for different each node? If yes, how different is it? Maybe show an example of the css? The way I do it is: create a function in the .theme file to generate a variable to use in the twig template, then add a style tag in node.html.twig and let the variable do the work based on the node. Maybe it wont work for your case, but I will need to see the CSS differences for the nodes and what needs to be generated.

Comment: This seems way over engineered to me. Why not use something like Panels or Display Suite to dictate layout per node? Responsive should work without needing to set CSS per device per node, contained all within the CSS itself. Why would breakpoints change from one page to the next in regards to mobile or tablet?

Comment: I'm pretty sure what you're trying to achieve can be done by generating necessary classes and related CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're over-engineering things here.

If your CSS is per-node-specific and stored in the DB anyways, then why not just use a text field to store the CSS? You just need to create a field template to output the raw content of the field in a `<style scoped>` tag.

Comment: Agree, something really bad is happening here then.

Comment: Updated my question. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Seeing your screenshot I would advice not to use any dynamic/inline CSS at all. The only thing you need is dynamic CSS class injection (can be done either in template preprocess or twig) and the same CSS for all nodes.

Comment: Can you please help me to understand with an example how should I do this in template preprocess? Currently, I am included in twig file like {% if cssFile is not empty %}
    <style media="all">
    @import url("{{cssFile}}");
    </style>
{% endif %}

Comment: The content type row has 3 css fields for desktop, tablet and mobile. These fields need to be compiled and added to the css. As Drupal requires css files to be added to libraries at installation / cache rebuilding, we have to add the css using a script tag in the block template.
In _block_module.html.twig template, I have imported this css. Is any way to add the css of rows without rendering it in the block template??

Comment: I think the CSS does not need to be compiled dynamically, nore does it need to be added dynamically. You need 9 unique classes in your CSS (3 responsive sizes * 3 css fields). Add the library containing those classes to your template (independent of settings in admin UI). The dynamic parts are the CSS class names added to the HTML/Twig template, not the CSS! E.g. in `YOURTHEME_preprocess_block` do something like `$variables['attributes']['class'][] = $cssClassNameFetchedFromField`